# If statement for catergories

Tags: categories

I was wondering if someone could explain how to roughly code this into php:

```
if catergory = Cars && user is unregistered
<my code>
else
<my code>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( is_category( 'Cars' ) && 0 == $current_user->ID ) { ?>

<!-- HTML markup here -->

<?php } else { ?>

<!-- other HTML markup here -->

<?php } ?>
```

ID will be 0 in the `$current_user` object, if the user isn't logged in.

Related reading:

- [`is_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)
- [`wp_get_current_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)

**EDIT**

Try using [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) and [`in_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) instead:

```
<?php
if ( in_category( 'cars' ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Current post is in the category 'cars'
    // and the current user is NOT logged in;
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
?>
```

Comment: Note: you could also use [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) in place of querying the current user. Might be a bit cleaner...

Comment: Alright, so only half of the code is working for me. It doesn't kick in the code for category cars and not being logged in. It just skips right to the else. Any ideas? Does it matter if cars is a subcatergory?

EDIT: I took out the "category( 'Cars' ) &&" and the code works if I'm logged out. So basically I narrowed down that it is the category code that isn't working properly. Suggestions?

Comment: `is_category` takes the category id, slug or title as an argument. If it doesn't do it's job, your category's title is not "Cars". Btw, +1 for @Chip

Comment: I took out the code "&& 0== $current_user->ID" and it still doesn't work. I created a new category named "test" and put it on a post and I also put "test" in the code and no luck.
do you think it could be from my custom layout? Maybe I didn't call some Category thing?

Comment: Feed it the category ID, just to be failsafe, but the conditional tag `is_category` works independent of your theme / layout. Are you sure you're testing this correctly? Can you put into words what it is you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve:
if the category is cars and you are not logged in you do not show the post.
else
show the post.

Comment: I don't know how to find the category ID but, I found the slug and it was "cars" not "Cars", so I changed it and still no luck.

Comment: Use **[`in_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category)** (to return `true` when the current post is *in* the specified Category, rather than `is_category()`, which returns true when the specified Category's *Archive Index Page* is being displayed.

Comment: Note: I've updated the original answer with `is_user_logged_in()` and `in_category()`.

Comment: Whose code should I use though? Because the original post had three php's and the edited version only has one.

Comment: Alright, so I just used the original code by Johannes and switched out the if statement with Chips code. Awesome. Works perfectly. Thank you guys so much. I'm new to this whole website. Is there something I do to acknowledge your help?